React Native - make text break into several lines
I have the following layout:
<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
  <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</Text>
  <Image source={require('some.png')} />
</View>

I want the text to have the width of the image and break into multiple lines automatically. Is it possible without obtaining the image width and setting the container or text width programmatically?

One way to do this is by using the flexShrink property on the text component and flex properties to ensure the image determines the width.
here is the updated code :
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
      </Text>
      <Image source={require('./some.png')} style={styles.image} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },
  text: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flexShrink: 1,
    flexBasis: 'auto',
  },
  image: {
    width: 100, 
    height: 100, 
  },
});

